# Using a typescript getter or local variable for a service variable in Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

So let's say you have an array of objects in a service

```
export class DataService {

  private _dataSources : Array<DataSource>

  contructor(private callerService: CallerService){
    this._dataSources = this.callerService.getDataSources(); // getting data from another service
  }

  // getter for _dataSources
  get dataSources(): Array<Datasource> {
    return this._dataSources;
  }
}
```

I want to use the array of dataSources in the for loop of an component that we shall call "DataComponent"

```
@Component({
  selector: 'data-component',
  template: `
       <div *ngFor="let dataSource of dataService.dataSources"></div> // one way
       <div *ngFor="let dataSource of dataSources"></div> // other way
     `,
  styleUrls: ['./data.component.css']
})
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {

  public dataSources: Array<DataSource>

  constructor(public dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() { 
   this.dataSources = this.dataService.dataSources(); 
  }
```

So the question here is, what is the best way of doing the for loop, considering:

- DataSources can be a very large object of multiple datasheets (like an excel workbook)
- Code must be easily understandable by others

Are there any performance benefits, what is common practice in Angular?

I know that `this.dataSources = this.dataService.dataSources();`  is actually just a pointer in memory so this will not cause any performance differences I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let dataSource of dataSources"></div>
```

is negligibly more performant because `dataService` doesn't need to be checked on change detection, `dataSources` getter function doesn't need to be called every time.

If `dataService.dataSources` is used more than once in the component or its children, `dataSources` component property allows to keep the code a bit DRYer and more readable.

In other aspects there's no difference.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!